# How does Stripe instantly update when a timestamp is reached?

Tags: architecture, queue, stripe-payments, publish-subscribe, payment-processing

I am trying to understand how a service like Stripe is able to instantly update when a timestamp, such as a subscription end date, is reached. I'm guessing it's not just a matter of having a timer with a callback function, since that would likely be too inefficient and unreliable given the immense number of subscriptions they manage.

I'm somewhat familiar with concepts such as Polling, Pub/Sub, and triggers; but I'm not sure if they're relevant in this case. Polling makes no sense as it would require constant requests to the database. I'm not familiar with triggers that can activate upon a timestamp being reached, and [my research](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83368/can-i-trigger-events-based-on-timestamp-data-or-should-i-use-polling) suggested this is true. Pub/Sub appears to be the most likely implementation approach I can think of, however, I cannot seem to figure out how it would be done.

I'm wondering if anyone has insights on how this might be implemented, possibly with the use of a queue or some other mechanism. Any thoughts or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guest is they might use a cron-like system, and re-evaluate by a batch when the times come, given the fact that all time in Stripe object are UTC-based.

Comment: if a subscription should end on December 28th @ 3:44 PM UTC, do you think that would be batched every minutes or at some higher interval? @orakaro